# How to fix editable index problem in angular

Tags: html, arrays, angular

I have two ngFor in a div and in same table, one ngFor array holds some existing data while the second one holds new data that I want to edit before pushing the data to the first array that olds thedefault/existing data.

My problem is, when I click edit button on a row in the second array, the same index/row of the array one also get aktivated for editing. I want the indexes of each array to be independent, that is, when I clicked the edit button on index of either of the array only the index should be activated, how to I fix that? below is my code:

**html**

```
<div>
 <table >
   <tr>//.....</tr>
         // olds existing data, in which the data in the "newData" array with later land
   <tr *ngFor="list of existingData"; let i=index;>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
          (click)=remove(i) [disabled]="disabled">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
          </button></td>
      <td><span>{{list.type}}</span><input type="test" *ngIf="enableEdit && enableEditIndex == i"></td>
      <td><button type="button"
        *ngIf="i != enableEditIndex || enableEditIndex == null"
        (click)="enableEditMethod($event, i )">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
      </button></td>
   </tr>
               // here is the second tr
   <tr *ngFor="list1 of newData">
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
          (click)=remove(i)>
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
          </button></td>
      <td><span>{{list1.type}}</span><input type="test" *ngIf="enableEdit && enableEditIndex == i"></td>
      <td><button type="button"
        *ngIf="i != enableEditIndex || enableEditIndex == null"
        (click)="enableEditMethod($event, i )">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
      </button></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</div>

// this is array from which data is push to "newData" array
<div>
 <table >
   <tr>//.....</tr>
   <tr *ngFor="allData of ArrayAllData">
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
          (click)=addObj(i)>
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
          </button></td>
      <td>{{allData.type}}</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Why I am have the two array is that "existingData" has cancel button disabled while "newData" is not.

**ts**

```
.....//some declarations

enableEditMethod( e, i ) {
   this.enableEdit = true; 
   this.enableEditIndex = i; 
}
```

I am using the same function on both button. In case of questions, please ask!

Comment: It was a miss there, I have the index in my code, but still same problem

Comment: Do you mind creating a sample stackblitz replicating the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's because you haven't initialized a second index variable for the second `*ngFor`.

Doing that would fix the issue:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>//.....</tr>
    <tr *ngFor="list of existingData" ; let i=index;>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)=remove(i) [disabled]="disabled">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
          </button></td>
      <td><span>{{list.type}}</span><input type="test" *ngIf="enableEdit && enableEditIndex == i"></td>
      <td><button type="button" *ngIf="i != enableEditIndex || enableEditIndex == null" (click)="enableEditMethod($event, i )">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
      </button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr *ngFor="list1 of newData; let newIndex = index">
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)=remove(newIndex)>
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
          </button></td>
      <td><span>{{list1.type}}</span><input type="test" *ngIf="enableEdit && enableEditIndex == newIndex"></td>
      <td><button type="button" *ngIf="newIndex != enableEditIndex || enableEditIndex == null" (click)="enableEditMethod($event, newIndex )">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
      </button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

// this is array from which data is push to "newData" array
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>//.....</tr>
    <tr *ngFor="allData of ArrayAllData">
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)=addObj(newIndex)>
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
          </button></td>
      <td>{{allData.type}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this approach but the problem still remains. A question here, can I change the second index name in html file without changing anything in ts file?

Comment: Yes of course. It's a variable named `newIndex` that's created on the fly.

Comment: Thanks, I have created a new function with the index name and it works.